# Microsoft Academic Graph: get all attributes for a paper

Tags: graph, https, response, document.evaluate

**How can I retrieve all the attributes of a paper entity?**
PS: There is an "optional" field named attributes in which you can specify which attributes you want to be in the response but removing this option will return nothing.
And if you put all the attributes manually it does not seem to function well. Some of them are not retrieved at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Id=1143723981&attributes=*
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks this worked on the demo page, and I assume it will also work with the REST API (which I am using). It is a bit strange because this was the first thing I did when i had this issue but it did not work at that time, so I added all of the attribute as a work around (Id,Ti,L,Y,D,CC,ECC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId,AA.AfN,AA.AfId,AA.S,F.FN,F.FId,J.JN,J.JId,C.CN,C.CId,RId,W,E). Now, it seems working fine.